# How can I disable browser form resubmission popup?

Tags: javascript, tcl

I have a tool written in TCL. It uses ajax and the code is wrapped in a form in a single page/domain.

Now, when I click around ajax does what it supposed to do, but when I refresh the page, I keep getting a "Are you sure you want to resubmit this form" popup.

The script below actually does remove the resubmission popup, but goes back to the initial state/function in the ajax. I'm not a js expert, how can I make sure the popup is removed but at the same time stay/call the previous ajax state/function. Thx.

```js
if ( window.history.replaceState ) { 
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href ); 
}
```

Comment: Fix your app problem so it doesn't try to resubmit on page reload. Don't try to take away user controls.

Comment: Read what I wrote first. The tool is based on a form, its the programming language.

Comment: This appears to be a Javascript/web-form problem. What does it have to do with the Tcl programming language? (Make the response from a POST be a redirect to a page that is retrieved with GET.)